# API works fine using Postman but not working using requests.post(): showing error ["No file was submitted."]

Tags: rest, python-requests

This function read the video file then send it to the server, it is working fine using postman but this method throws an error Failed to upload file: {"footage":["No file was submitted."]}

def upload_sequence(self):

```
    print("upload started")
    FOLDER_PATH = f"./recordings/recordings{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}"
    
    create_folder(f"./outputs/output{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}")
    
    OUTPUT_PATH = f"./outputs/output{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}/output_combined_video{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}.avi"

    print("combined started")
    combine_videos(FOLDER_PATH,OUTPUT_PATH)
    print("video combined")
    print(OUTPUT_PATH)
    
    try:
        with open(OUTPUT_PATH, "rb") as file:
            files = {'file': file}
            upload_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/'
            headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + self.CONNECT_URL}
            
            print(headers)

            # Send POST request to upload file
            print(files)
            upload_response = requests.post(upload_url, files=files, headers=headers)

            # Check response
            if upload_response.status_code == 201:  
                print("File uploaded successfully.")
                messagebox.showinfo("Prompt", "File uploaded successfully.")
            else:
                print("Failed to upload file:", upload_response.text)
                messagebox.showinfo("Prompt", "Failed to upload file")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        messagebox.showinfo("Prompt", f"Error occurred: {e}")
```

I need to send a post with a file  request using requests.post() method